# In C: File Not Found Error When using readInputFile function for a second time on fclose()

Tags: c, linux, file, visual-studio-code, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to read two different .txt files to compare them later in my code. For this project, I needed to dynamically allocate the files since I am not allowed a max character size. My function correctly gets the file information correctly on the first run, but it crashes with an error on the second run when reading the second input file. The Error being: Error: File Not Found. Any idea on what is causing it to fail during the second run? Thanks

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    struct stat stringBuffer1; 
    struct stat stringBuffer2;
    stat(argv[1], &stringBuffer1); 
    stat(argv[2], &stringBuffer2); 
    FILE *textFile1 = NULL, *textFile2 = NULL, *outputFile = NULL; 
    textFile1=fopen(argv[1], "r");
    textFile2=fopen(argv[2], "r");
    char* fileString1;
    char* fileString2;
    printf("code before readInputFile");
    fileString1 = strdup(readInputFile(textFile1,stringBuffer1));
    fileString2 = strdup(readInputFile(textFile2,stringBuffer2));

char* readInputFile(FILE* targetFile, struct stat stringBuffer)
{       
    char *tempString=malloc(stringBuffer.st_size+1); 
    fread(tempString, 1, stringBuffer.st_size, targetFile); 
    fclose(targetFile); //Error happens here
    char* finalString = &tempString[stringBuffer.st_size];
    tempString[stringBuffer.st_size]=0; // Setting 0-Byte
    strcpy(finalString,tempString);
    free(tempString);
    return finalString;
}
```

Comment: `char* finalString = &tempString[stringBuffer.st_size];` is initialized to an address within `tempString`, then you `free(tempString);`. `finalString` points to an address that is no longer valid. Also, since `tempString` and `finalString` overlap, the use of `strcpy` is undefined. See [C11 Standard - 7.24.2.3 The strcpy function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.2.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got undefined behavior here, and everything else is likely broken by it. The problem is that:

```
char *tempString=malloc(stringBuffer.st_size+1);
```

allocates memory,

```
char* finalString = &tempString[stringBuffer.st_size];
```

makes a pointer to (almost) the end of said memory, then:

```
strcpy(finalString,tempString);
```

is both undefined in and of itself (`strcpy` requires that source and destination not overlap) and even if it "works", it writes *way* past the end of said memory (possibly indefinitely, since it blows away the `NUL` termination byte you just wrote on the first byte copied). To add insult to injury,

```
free(tempString);
```

frees what little validly allocated memory `finalString` actually refers to, so the `return` is returning a pointer that can't be legally dereferenced (`strdup` is both reading from an invalid pointer, and likely allocating from a corrupted heap).

The error you're seeing is likely caused by this willy-nilly stomping on heap memory you don't own.

If you want this to work, the simplest approach is to return the `malloc`ed memory without `free`ing it, leaving it up to the caller to `free` it when they're done. You don't copy the data around (it's already where you want it to be after all):

```
char* readInputFile(FILE* targetFile, struct stat stringBuffer)
{       
    char *tempString=malloc(stringBuffer.st_size+1); 
    fread(tempString, 1, stringBuffer.st_size, targetFile);
    tempString[stringBuffer.st_size] = '\0';
    fclose(targetFile);
    return tempString;
}
```

Remove the `strdup` wrappers in your `main` (it's already getting dynamically allocated memory back), and just add `free(fileString1);` and `free(fileString2);` to `main` after you're done with the data returned.

Comment: That about covers it -- hard to know where to start `:)`